# Initializing 2D Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, chess

I'm trying to create an array whereby a 2 character code in each element corresponds to what pieces are where on a chessboard.However, I can't work out how do use the 2D arrays. I have the pieceArray declared as:

Public pieceArray(7,7) as String

And then I'm trying to populate it using this method:

```
pieceArray =      {"BR", "Bk", "BB", "BQ", "BK", "BB", "Bk", "BR",
                   "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP", "BP",
                   "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ",
                   "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ",
                   "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ",
                   "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  ",
                   "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP", "WP",
                   "WR", "Wk", "WB", "WQ", "WK", "WB", "Wk", "WR"}
```

But this method gives me an error where the dimensions don't match up so could you please explain how to do this properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not how you access read/write data to a 2D array. It looks more like that:

```
' an array with 5 rows and 2 columns
Dim a(4,1) As Integer
```

Hard coding the way you are doing it would work like this:

```
Module arrayApl
   Sub Main()
      ' an array with 5 rows and 2 columns
      Dim a(,) As Integer = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}
      Dim i, j As Integer
      ' output each array element's value '
      For i = 0 To 4
          For j = 0 To 1
              Console.WriteLine("a[{0},{1}] = {2}", i, j, a(i, j))
          Next j
      Next i
      Console.ReadKey()
   End Sub
End Module
```

Maybe [take a look at a tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm).

Comment: the beginning is wrong (and a frequent mistake, the OP did the same in his question). this `Dim a(5, 2) As Integer` declares an array of **6 * 3** items because in the declaration you're not putting the length of the dimension but it's final index. you can write it (and it compiles fine) `Dim a(0 To 5, 0 To 2) As Integer` and know it's obvious that the sizes are 6 and 3. (that doesn't apply to the rest of your code, the dimension are inferred from the definition given after `=` sign)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @StefanFalk Is there no way to do this without doing that as there is in other languages? I'm trying to build a chessboard so it would be easier if I could have some sort of visualisation of how the data in the array is organised.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Is there no way to do this without doing that as there is in other languages?*"? To access data inside an array by `myArray(i,j)` is quite straight forward, isn't it? I can't really answer your question. I'd need to know which languages you already know, you are allowed to use or you want to learn. I don't know what you're exactly trying to do atm.